# Bad credentials with a custom guard authenticator and a custom user provider

Tags: symfony

I am building a REST Api with Symfony 4.3 and I have a problem with authentication (user/password) using a custom user provider and a custom guard.

***The context***

Users have to authenticate themselves on a specific endpoint /api/auth/login with a user/password in order to get a JWT Token. All users are stored in a user table with the following informations :

- login
- password (NOT mandatory !)
- authentication method ('**LDAP**' or '**LOCAL**')

If the authentication method is defined on 'LOCAL', we use the login/password define in the user table in order to authenticate it. It the authentication method is defined on 'LDAP', I want to use only the login (no password stored in the database) and I authenticate the user against the LDAP.

I have created a custom User provider to manage my User class and I have created a custom Guard Authenticator in order to manage the 2 authentication methods :

```
class MyUserAuthenticator extends AbstractGuardAuthenticator
    {
    private $em;
    private $logger;
    private $userRepository;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em, TUserRepository $userRepository)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
    }

    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        $this->logger->info('[UserAuthenticator] getCredentials()');
        $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
        if(isset($data['username']) && isset($data['password'])) {
            $credentials = [
                'username' => $data['username'],
                'password' => $data['password'],
            ];

            return $credentials;
        } else {
            throw new BadCredentialsException('username or/and password missing in login request.');
        } 
    }

    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        $this->logger->info('[UserAuthenticator] getUser()');
        return $this->userRepository->find($credentials['username']);
    }

    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
    {       
        if($user){
            $mode = $user->getAuthMethod();
            switch($mode) {
                case 'LDAP':
                    // CHECK ON LDAP
                    break;
                case 'LOCAL':
                    // CHECK password with the User Provider
                    // if($user->getPassword() == credentials['password']) { return true; } else { return false; }
                    break;
                default:
                    return false;
                    break;
            }
        }

        // return true to cause authentication success
        return false;
    }

}
```

***The problem***

The checkCredentials() of my custom authenticator guard works perfectly, it return TRUE and I'm authenticated with the guard (Guard authentication successful in the log file). 
But after that it seems that there is another authentication process handle by Symfony which checks the password and finally the authentication fails if I use the LDAP authen method (no password in the database) :

> [2019-09-27 17:02:55] security.INFO: Authentication request failed. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\BadCredentialsException(code: 0): Bad credentials. at /var/www/my.api/vendor/symfony/security-core/Authentication/Provider/UserAuthenticationProvider.php:85, Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\BadCredentialsException(code: 0): The presented password is invalid. at /var/www/my.api/vendor/symfony/security-core/Authentication/Provider/DaoAuthenticationProvider.php:59)"} []

I don't understrand why the password is checked, I justly have decided to create my custom authenticator guard in order to implement a custom password management...

***The log file :***

```
[2019-09-27 17:02:55] request.INFO: Matched route "api_auth_login". {"route":"api_auth_login","route_parameters":{"_route":"api_auth_login"},"request_uri":"https://my.api/api/auth/login","method":"POST"} []
[2019-09-27 17:02:55] security.DEBUG: Checking for guard authentication credentials. {"firewall_key":"api_login","authenticators":1} []
[2019-09-27 17:02:55] security.DEBUG: Checking support on guard authenticator. {"firewall_key":"api_login","authenticator":"App\\Security\\UserAuthenticator"} []
[2019-09-27 17:02:55] security.DEBUG: Calling getCredentials() on guard authenticator. {"firewall_key":"api_login","authenticator":"App\\Security\\UserAuthenticator"} []
[2019-09-27 17:02:55] app.INFO: [UserAuthenticator] getCredentials() [] []
[2019-09-27 17:02:55] security.DEBUG: Passing guard token information to the GuardAuthenticationProvider {"firewall_key":"api_login","authenticator":"App\\Security\\UserAuthenticator"} []
[2019-09-27 17:02:55] app.INFO: [UserAuthenticator] getUser() [] []
[2019-09-27 17:02:55] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT [.......] WHERE t0.USERID = ? ["THEUSER"] []
[2019-09-27 17:02:55] app.INFO: [UserAuthenticator] checkCredentials() [] []
[2019-09-27 17:02:55] security.INFO: Guard authentication successful! {"token":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Guard\\Token\\PostAuthenticationGuardToken: PostAuthenticationGuardToken(user=\"THEUSER\", authenticated=true, roles=\"SUPERVISER\"))","authenticator":"App\\Security\\UserAuthenticator"} []
[2019-09-27 17:02:55] security.DEBUG: Guard authenticator set no success response: request continues. {"authenticator":"App\\Security\\UserAuthenticator"} []
[2019-09-27 17:02:55] security.DEBUG: Remember me skipped: it is not configured for the firewall. {"authenticator":"App\\Security\\UserAuthenticator"} []
[2019-09-27 17:02:55] app.INFO: loadUserByUsername() [] []
[2019-09-27 17:02:55] security.INFO: Authentication request failed. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\BadCredentialsException(code: 0): Bad credentials. at /var/www/my.api/vendor/symfony/security-core/Authentication/Provider/UserAuthenticationProvider.php:85, Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\BadCredentialsException(code: 0): The presented password is invalid. at /var/www/my.api/vendor/symfony/security-core/Authentication/Provider/DaoAuthenticationProvider.php:59)"} []
```

Comment: Is this the entire code of your class `MyUserAuthenticator `? I don't see the implementation of all methods.

Comment: No it is not the entire code, the others inherited methods have been implemented properly.

Comment: Well I will double check onAuthenticationSuccess and onAuthenticationFailure, since they are next methods executed after check credentials. Maybe you can log info in both of them to see what is really going on.